# How are all favorable cases obtained quickly?

Tags: probability

I have a statement that says:

> When throwing two dice, what is the probability that the sum of your
>   points will be a multiple of 5?

Ok, its a classic probability, then:

$\frac{favorable-cases}{6^2}$,

In all the exercises that I have seen, to obtain the favorable cases, they simply start to see them one by one.

That seems like a waste of time, and if they were 50 dice ?, then how are the favorable cases obtained, without seeing one by one?

Comment: For fifty dice, at that point you would likely want to use a computer's help in calculating anyways.  To do that, you could look at the expansion of the generating function $(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^{50}$ and run a loop, adding the respective coefficients of $x^5,x^{10},x^{15},\dots,x^{300}$ from the expansion.

Comment: that still applying to two dice ?

Comment: For the question with only two dice, with practice you should know rather quickly that there are $4$ ways to get a sum of $5$ and there are $3$ ways to get a sum of $10$.  (*the number of ways to get a sum of 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 are 1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1 respectively.  Start at six ways to get a sum of 7 and decrease by one for each step away from 7 you go*).  Don't bother listing them out individually, you may miss some.  Just make sure you know *how many* there are.

Comment: For two dice, you could use generating functions as well, just the exponent on the parenthetical phrase would only be $2$ instead of $50$.  $(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^2=x^2+2x^3+3x^4+4x^5+5x^6+6x^7+5x^8+\dots+x^{12}$

Comment: So you are mixing the $3$ ways of get a sum of $10$ and a sum of $5$ for get the $7$ favorable cases ?¿

Comment: Yes, there are seven favorable equiprobable cases for your original question with two dice.

Comment: Alternative way: Given the value of the first die, there is usually (namely, when the first die shows anything but $4$) one and only one value for the second die to produce a multiple of $5$. The only exception is when both values $1$ and $6$ produce a multiple of $5$, which happens iff the first value was $4$. Hence the probability is $\frac56\cdot \frac16+\frac16\cdot \frac 26$.